# Best way for conda environment to use individual ipython and matplotlib config files

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, conda, miniconda

I just installed miniconda on mac in order to use python 3. But I have python 2 installed the old fashioned way that I want to preserve. The old configuration files for ipython and matplotlib are in my home directory at the default locations (~/.ipython/profile_default/ and ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc).

I thought I would use the conda environments to isolate my new python3 so I made a new "main" environment with

```
conda create --name=main
```

and installed ipython and matplotlib in my new environment

```
conda activate main
conda install ipython matplotlib
```

What is a good way for my new ipython and matplotlib to use their own configuration files? I want to keep the old config files in place so I can still use my old python 2 if I need to.

My tiny bit of progress was that in my new `main` conda environment I ran `ipython profile create condaenv_main`, which created a new ipython profile in ~/.ipython/profile_condaenv_main. Is there a way that I can have ipython load this profile automatically if I'm in this environment (maybe with some aliases or something)? I.e. I would like to be able to type

```
conda activate main
ipython
```

rather than

```
conda activate main
ipython --profile=condaenv_main
```

Right now the first way would load my old profile_default ipython which I don't want.

Is there an analogous way I can keep the conda `main` environment's matplotlib config also separate just for `main`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

For ipython I followed the idea [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11862) to define the alias
`alias ipython="ipython --profile=condaenv_main"`
when the environment is activated and `unalias ipython` when deactivated. The instructions are [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux).

For matplotlib I created a subdirectory of ~/.matplotlib called condaenv_main/ and put my new matplotlibrc file in there. Then I have conda set the environment variable `MPLCONFIGDIR` when environment is activated (and it is automatically removed when environment is deactivated). The command is (see [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#setting-environment-variables)):

`conda env config vars set MPLCONFIGDIR=$HOME/.matplotlib/condaenv_main`